# Java Google App Engine won't send email via Mailgun SMTP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, smtp, mailgun

I have followed through the tutorials and set up the GCP firewalls for both ingress and outgress on the port 2525. Running the code locally on my machine successfully sends the email however, deploying the project to App Engine Standard (Java runtime) does not throw an error but also does not send the email.

I also have a GCP VM instance that is also able to send the email. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Dependencies : 
[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SzyW.png)

```
    String email = "target@email.com";
    String API_KEY = "KEY";

    HttpResponse<JsonNode> req = Unirest.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + "my.custom.domain" + "/messages")
            .basicAuth("api", API_KEY)
            .field("from","Admin <admin@my.custom.domain>")
            .field("to", email)
            .field("subject","Welcome!")
            .field("text", "testing")
            .asJson();
    req.getBody();
```

throws : 
        `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
         at tech.incineratez.email.Main.main(Main.java:14)
    Caused by: kong.unirest.UnirestException: It looks like you are using an 
    older version of Apache Http Client. 
    For security and performance reasons Unirest requires the most recent 
    version. Please upgrade.
    at kong.unirest.Config.setDefaults(Config.java:109)
    at kong.unirest.Config.<init>(Config.java:85)
    at kong.unirest.Unirest.<clinit>(Unirest.java:30)
    ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
    no such constructor: kong.unirest.apache.ApacheAsyncClient.<init> 
    (Config)void/newInvokeSpecial
    at kong.unirest.Config.setDefaults(Config.java:106)
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such constructor: 
    kong.unirest.apache.ApacheAsyncClient.<init>(Config)void/newInvokeSpecial
    at
java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:483)
    ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/apache/http/nio/reactor/ConnectingIOReactor
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750)
    at
java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ConnectingIOReactor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more`

Working code if ran seperately on my computer and not on the Google Cloud Platform :

```
                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.mailgun.org");
                props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtps.port", "2525");

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@my.custom.domain"));

                InternetAddress[] addrs = InternetAddress.parse(email, false);
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addrs);

                msg.setSubject("Welcome!");
                msg.setText("Test");
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());

                SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");
                t.connect("smtp.mailgun.org", "postmaster@my.custom.domain", "KEY");
                t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

                System.out.println("Email sent" + t.getLastServerResponse());

                t.close();
```

Dependencies : [Dependencies2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsIh.png)

The code above when ran on the Google Cloud Platform does nothing at all.

Comment: You should use Mailgun's REST API instead of trying to send via SMTP

Comment: I started out trying to use their API which resulted in hours of debugging errors and getting the dependencies needed by their dependencies which ultimately, didn't work.

Comment: Ok, their REST API _does_ work, so it's worth figuring that out if you plan to use Mailgun.

Comment: I've just tried using their API, made sure all the dependencies were latest, and it threw at me : `Caused by: kong.unirest.UnirestException: It looks like you are using an older version of Apache Http Client. 
For security and performance reasons Unirest requires the most recent version. Please upgrade.
 at kong.unirest.Config.setDefaults(Config.java:109)`                                                 and a bunch more errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are talking about [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) to configure the sending of mails through Compute Engine (which explains why it works well on your VM instance).

That tutorial is for Compute Engine, in the case of App Engine Standard applications, you have the option of using [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/), however, since [Google is no longer accepting quota increases](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes#1.9.36) for that API, is advised to use a third-party service such as MailGun or SendGrid.

To connect your App Engine standard application (with Java runtime) with those third-party services you will need to specify the "dependicies" on your "pom.xml" file and modify your "app.yaml" with the API Key:

```
env_variables:
     EMAIL_API_KEY: key-from-third-party
```

The Email API Key will be provided by the third-party service, for example, in the case of MailGun, their [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication) specifies the following:

> When you sign up for an account, you are given an API key. You
>   authenticate to the Mailgun API by providing your API key in the
>   request. You can manage your API key in the “Security” tab under the
>   Account section of the Control Panel.

For the step by step instructions on how to configure your App Engine Standard App to connect with these third-party services, please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-messages).

**EDIT:**

It looks like in your case, you could be using another dependencies (hence, the dependency error). When you created the code did you refereed to the App Engine Java 8 documentation samples or to the Mailgun samples? because I noticed they use different dependencies, and also the App Engine sample uses env variables (which according to the snippet code you shared, you are not using).

My advice is to follow the sample given for [Google App Engine Standard Java 8](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/mailgun).

**These are the steps I took to get the sample successfully up and running on App Engine:**

**1.** Downloaded the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/mailgun).

**2.** Created an account on [Mailgun](https://signup.mailgun.com/new/signup) (simple account, not credit data attached). You will need to verify your account through the specified email.

**3.** Once your are logged inside MailGun, you will see a menu on the left, navigate to Sending > Overview page.

**4.** At the right you will see an "Authorized Recipients" box, add the email or the person that will receive the email, they will need to confirm also on their side, so try adding an email on which you have access for the sake of the test. Note: you need to do this if you haven't [verified your domain](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain).

**5.** Copy the value of the domain you have for default (or the one you have verified).

**6.** On the same box there's a menu with the link to "Api Keys", click on it and copy the key under "HTTP webhook signing key" (this is also your private key, so be careful where you put it).

**7.** Head to the GCP sample that was downloaded, and edit the file **"/mailgun/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml"** with those values (domain and key).

**8.** If you are using Maven run the commands:

```
mvn appengine:run  (if you want to test locally)
```

or

```
mvn appengine:deploy (if you want to deploy to App Engine)
```

**note:** some of these steps might have look rather obvious for you but I have explained it this way so other people can follow it as well.

Comment: I am not using any build automation system, so all dependencies are manually added via JAR files. The code that i'm using right now runs fine in a standard CLI application that's ran on my computer, which does not specify the need of an API Key.

Comment: Could you clarify what is that you are trying to accomplish? (where are you trying to deploy your app). I have understood you are trying to deploy an App Engine Standard app with Java runtime (according to the tags on the question), but now you have mentioned a CLI application. Depending on where are you planning to deploy the application, will vary the configuration needed.

Comment: It is indeed and App Engine Standard app with Java Runtime. What I meant by the CLI application is to show that when I copy paste the code where I attempt to send an email to a normal command line app to test the code, it works, but not in the App Engine Standard Environment. The application is deployed in the servers in Singapore.

Comment: In that case, according to the App Engine standard documentation, you will need to provide a Mail API Key, which you will get on the third-party mail service. In the Case of MailGun, their documentation specifies: "When you sign up for an account, you are given an API key. You authenticate to the Mailgun API by providing your API key in the request. You can manage your API key in the “Security” tab under the Account section of the Control Panel." (https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication)
I will edit the answer to add the extra details

Comment: I am aware of the API Key and have provided it, but when I try to use their API, it throws an error saying that my dependencies are out of date - which they arent. unirest/Config.java: `        try {
            asyncBuilder = ApacheAsyncClient::new;
            clientBuilder = ApacheClient::new;
        }catch (BootstrapMethodError e){
            throw new UnirestException("It looks like you are using an older version of Apache Http Client. \n" +
                    "For security and performance reasons Unirest requires the most recent version. Please upgrade.", e);
        }
    } `

Comment: where does that error appears? locally? it seems to point out that your Apache Http Client dependency is out of date, you mentioned that you are not using an automatic build system but the dependencies are manually added via JAR files, could you clarify which version of Apache Http Client are you using? and also, if you could update your original question with that information along with another details such as: your current development set up and a minimal reproducible example (without sensitive information) it could help us understand where the issue is coming from and how to resolve it.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the requested details.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you might be using other dependencies which could be causing conflicts, for the sake of the test I have tried to deploy a sample app using the code shared by GCP, and I was able to successfully deploy the application. I have updated my answer in case you want to compare on what you have on your code (or what you have done so far) that could be missing from the working sample.

Comment: I have following through your steps and upon loading the servlet it throws a 500 Server Error :  ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/ClientFilter `, which is odd as it exists within the package. I have also made sure that my dependencies are correct : jersey-client-1.19.4, jersey-core-1.19.4, jersey-multipart-1.19.4 and jsr311-api-1.1.1 (javax.ws.rs).

Comment: Follow Up : I moved my entire project to use Maven and everything went smoothly, thanks for your help :).

Comment: no problem, I'm glad to hear you got everything working properly : )